# Changing the Spool Folder of Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

In my `NEO-MAIL.xml` file, I see the entry as:

```
<var name='spooldir'>
    <string>{neo.rootdir}/Mail/Spool</string>
</var>
```

My ColdFusion is installed on `C:\`, which is running low on space, so I want to move the spool to a different directory, say `D:\`. Is this a possibility?

As of now, I have not tried it yet, because I am not sure if it might break the ColdFusion Administrator. So I am looking for some advice. Is there is a possibility of changing the path without breaking things? If no, how can I make this change?

Comment: If you create a backup file you can always revert it if necessary. It should work if you change it. Note that the path is using forward slashes

Comment: Note that there is also an Undelivr folder used by the ColdFusion mail subsystem. Both the Spool and Undelivr folders are normally located under a Mail parent folder. You may need to move that entire hierarchy (from Mail folder down) to keep things happy. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure you got this and as a reference to the future viewer, Do as follows:

1. Find neo-mail.xml file under coldfusion 10/11 > cfusion > lib
2. backup the neo-mail.xml file
3. In the neo-mail.xml file, change following line 
   `<var name="spooldir">
      <string>{neo.rootdir}/Mail/Spool</string>
   </var>` 
    to
   `<var name="spooldir">
      <string>Your path</string>
   </var>`
   e.g.
   `<var name="spooldir">
      <string>D:/MyMails/Spool</string>
   </var>`
4. Change another line 
    `<var name="undeliverdir">
       <string>{neo.rootdir}/Mail/Undelivr</string>
   </var>`
    to 
   `<var name="undeliverdir">
       <string>Your Path</string>
   </var>` 
    e.g. 
   `<var name="undeliverdir">
       <string>D:/MyMails/Undelivr</string>
   </var>`
5. Remember to keep both Undelivr and Spool folder under one directory.
6. Restart server and voila, Your job is done.